# Extra weird characters read from a file of certain bytes

Tags: c, csv, fread

My buffer made from "fread()"ing a csv file (in its entirety) prints unintelligible extra characters if the file is certain bytes long. I am following the standard approach to read the file (fseek(), ftell() and fread()). 
This problem occurs when my file's size lies roughly somewhere between 104 and 113 bytes.
1.Why does it happen in a certain range?
2.Solution?

Code:

```
int getfilesize(char *fname)
{
  FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  int size = ftell(fp);
  fclose(fp);
  return size;
}

int main()
{

int file_size=getfilesize("sample1.csv");
printf("\nsize of file:%d",file_size);

char* buf=(malloc(file_size+1));

FILE* fp=fopen("sample1.csv","r");
fread(buf,file_size,1,fp);
fclose(fp);
printf("\nstring is: \n%s\n",buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Erroneous file (a '4' printed in the next line for this file):
Sample1.csv (108 bytes on my system):
0x1001,0,0,0-100
0x1017,5,1,10:-20:-30:30:40:-90:-23
0x1011,4,1,5:10:20
0x1028,2,0,0-2,1
0x1021,1,1,1:2:4:8

Error-free file:
Sample1.csv (120 bytes on my system):
0x1001,0,0,0-100
0x1017,5,1,10:-20:-30:30:40:-90:-23
0x1011,4,1,5:10:20
0x1028,2,0,0-2,1
0x1021,1,1,1:2:4:8:10:12:13:14

Comment: I do not see the erroneously printed "4" you describe. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Try adding `buf[file_size]='\0'` before the `printf`. That is, you need to ensure that `buf` contains a string. The data read from a text file is not automatically a valid C  string and `malloc` does not explicitly init the memory to zero.

Comment: I think @kaylum is right; it seems like you are seeing extra random bytes after the valid data because the string is not correctly null-terminated. Setting the final byte to zero as they suggest will fix this.

Comment: Thanks, apparently adding a '\0' character did solve the issue. I assumed that we are declaring a "buf" of "f_size+1" so as to automatically insert the null character which is the case with regular string declarations as well. I wonder why there was a need to intervene. But still thanks again.

Comment: As I said, `malloc` allocates memory but doesn't write anything to it. So the contents of the memory contains unknown values. There is no "automatic insert" of anything as the memory can be used for any data type and not just strings.

Comment: `int size = ftell(fp);` -- what type does `ftell` return?

Comment: int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);

       long ftell(FILE *stream);

Comment: The ftell() function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream.
The  fseek() function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream.

Comment: GoonerZaid `long ftell()` returns a `long`, not `int`.  To save the result in `int size` loses information with huge files.  @DavidC.Rankin is hinting at code should be `long size = ftell(fp);`

Comment: oh! sorry for being so naive. Thanks David and Chux for pointing my mistake out.

Answer (score 1):

Code does not insure printing of a *string* as `buf` is not *null character* terminated.

Adjust code so `buf` is a *string*  or print with a width limitation.

```
// printf("\nstring is: \n%s\n",buf);
printf("\nstring is: \n%.*s\n", file_size, buf);
```